# QR Code Scanner Using GMS Vision, When i save it to Firebase it saves multiple data

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need help, im confused why evertime i scan using the scanner i created it saves multiple data on firestore here's my java code

```
public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {

    SparseArray<Barcode> qrcode = detections.getDetectedItems();
    if(qrcode.size()!=0){
        text.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                text.setText(qrcode.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put("Data", text.getText().toString());
                db.collection("Records").add(data).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                        Toast.makeText(Scanner.this, "inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It is successful but it saves multiple data. here is the firestore situation, all documents have the same content
[image]

Comment: So you say that instead of adding a single document, there are multiple documents added? Is that right? If yes, show us how your `receiveDetections()` is called.

Comment: Hi i have already fixed this problem by using other QR code scanner and its all good now thank you so much for your response :)